# Why am I getting this NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

Suddenly I'm getting the error below in my spring application and I can't see why.  I don't believe I've altered anything in my pom.xml file to cause this.  Has anyone any ideas on how I can fix the issue?

Error:

```
Aug 05, 2014 10:02:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Blue Coat\ProxyClient\;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Blue Coat\ProxyClient\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Blue Coat\ProxyClient\;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;H:\Notedata;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Lotus\Notes;C:\Program Files (x86)\Blue Coat\ProxyClient\;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Users\E048944\Software\gradle-1.11\\bin;C:\Users\E048944\Software\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin;C:\Users\E048944\Software\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY;C:\Users\E048944\Software\groovy-2.2.2\bin;C:\Users\E048944\Software\curl;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;H:\Notedata;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Lotus\Notes;C:\Program Files (x86)\Blue Coat\ProxyClient\;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;;C:\Users\E048944\Software\eclipse-jee-luna-win32-x86_64;;.
Aug 05, 2014 10:02:52 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:springdata_web' did not find a matching property.
Aug 05, 2014 10:02:52 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 05, 2014 10:02:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 468 ms
Aug 05, 2014 10:02:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 05, 2014 10:02:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.39
Aug 05, 2014 10:02:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2483)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2793)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 19 more

Aug 05, 2014 10:02:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Aug 05, 2014 10:02:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Aug 05, 2014 10:02:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/springdata_web] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 05, 2014 10:02:52 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 05, 2014 10:02:52 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Aug 05, 2014 10:02:52 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/13  config=null
Aug 05, 2014 10:02:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 510 ms
```

Here's my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>springdata</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.esb</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>springdata_web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>springdata_web</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <slf4jVersion>1.7.7</slf4jVersion>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.wimpi</groupId>
            <artifactId>telnetd-x</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>copy</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I googled the error and there were TONS of solutions, surely one of those will work.

Comment: I've tried everything I think at this stage. Maybe it's one of those I need to sleep on. I've been looking at it that long I'm going round in circles I think

Comment: did someone change your parent pom out form under you?

Comment: add spring-context dependency

Comment: I tried with spring-context dependency added but got the same error...

Comment: Could it be that m2e has an issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I renamed out my .m2 directory and re-ran the maven build and this resolved the problem.  Cache obviously got corrupted somehow.

Comment: Same issue got resolved after building in a fresh repository.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing different versions of Spring components.  For example, you have spring-orm 4.0.2.RELEASE and spring-beans 4.0.3.RELEASE.

I see that you're also using spring-data-rest-webmvc and spring-data-jpa.  These dependencies could also be pulling in unintended versions of Spring dependencies.  You can add exclusions to those dependencies to prevent that from happening.